# SQL query how to use two date variables? Both 'date' and regexp_replace('date', '-', ''),1,8)

Tags: python, sql, oracle

The SQL query was the partial code of the python file, tt1's `val` and tt2's `val` all work fine in single file, now I would like to calculate `tt1.val/tt2.val`, I have to input parameter `code`, `start_date` and `end_date`,

```
the date from table_name_a is '20191107'

the date from table_name_b is '2019-11-07 00:00:00'
```

That's the reason why I use `substr(regexp_replace(date,'-',''),1,8)` in table_name_b, I pasted my wrong SQL query as below, can I use `case when` or `if else` to use two different date variables? Thanks so much for any advice.

```
SELECT code, tt1.val/tt2.val
FROM (

    (
    SELECT code,
        CAST (exp(sum(ln(val+1))) -1 AS decimal(20,16)) val
    FROM (
        SELECT code, val
        from table_name_a
        WHERE code IN ('%(code)s')
        AND date BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s')
    GROUP BY code
    ) AS tt1
    (
    SELECT code,
        CAST (exp(sum(ln(val+1))) -1 AS decimal(20,16)) val
    FROM (
        SELECT code, val
        from table_name_b
        WHERE code IN ('%(code)s')
        AND substr(regexp_replace(date,'-',''),1,8) BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s' AS t1
    GROUP BY code
    ) AS tt1
) AS tt3
```

Comment: I don't see an actual problem statement here, just a bunch of code.  Please let us know where in this large SQL query the actual problem lies.

Comment: what is the data type of the date column in both the table? is it date data type in `table_name_b` and number data type in `table_name_a`?

Comment: @Tejash the date from table_name_a is '20191107' and the date from table_name_b is '2019-11-07 00:00:00', that's the reason why I use substr(regexp_replace(date,'-',''),1,8) in table_name_b

Comment: can you please provide the output of the `desc table_name_b`? and `desc table_name_a`?

Comment: Unfortunately you have redacted your code to the point where it has become nonsense: this query would not compile on Oracle database. You need to provide either fully working test case or a clear explanation of what you're trying to do. So please give us table structures, sample data, example parameter values and required output derived from the starting data and parameters. You don't have to give us your actual tables: simplified structures with just the columns referenced by your query.

Comment: @APC  @Tejash,  I just want to calculate the result from two different SQL query, but the data type of `%(start_date)s'` and `%(end_date)s'` is a different type, I am sorry, it still need table structures, sample data, example parameter values?

Comment: Are you saying this *"the date from table_name_a is"* is not a DATE datatype and *"the date from table_name_b is "* is also not a DATE datatype? If so, what data types are they?

Comment: @APC hi, '2019-11-07 00:00:00' from table_name_b is `DateField` and 20191107' from table_name_a is StringField

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to `JOIN` your queries:

```sql
SELECT tt1.code, tt1.val/tt2.val
FROM (SELECT code
           , CAST (exp(sum(ln(val+1))) -1 AS decimal(20,16)) val
        FROM table_name_a
       WHERE code IN ('%(code)s')
         AND date BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s'
       GROUP BY code) tt1
JOIN (SELECT code
           , CAST (exp(sum(ln(val+1))) -1 AS decimal(20,16)) val
        FROM table_name_b
       WHERE code IN ('%(code)s')
         AND substr(regexp_replace(date,'-',''),1,8) BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s'
       GROUP BY code) tt2
  ON tt2.code = tt1.code
```

Also simplified your query a little bit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it seems like a wrong SQL query too, because I got an error of `AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 13:
        ) AS tt1
          ^
Encountered: AS
Expected: LIMIT, ORDER, UNION

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error`

Comment: Edited query and removed the `AS` keywords as the can only be used in column-aliases not in table aliases...

Comment: Hey thanks again, I am not sure we can use SQL query like this, now I get `AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 13:
        ) tt1
          ^
Encountered: IDENTIFIER
Expected: LIMIT, ORDER, UNION

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

unable to rollback`

Comment: @Elsa - IDENTIFIER appears to be something you've introduced into the query . We can't diagnose your syntax errors without seeing the actual code you're executing.